# Encountered "Unknown Protocol " message while trying to share a text using WhatsApp in a website

Tags: html, whatsapp

I am using the following code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Hello%20World!">Send</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Please use Opera browser, right click on *Send* and click on *Open Link In New Tab*
Opera then shows an alert msg:
*Unknown Protocol:*
Opera was unable to open the link since no application associated with "whatsapp:" protocol was found on your system.
How come I am seeing the above msg.
And please give a solution.
*NB:* I didnt use to see the msg before. It appeared only now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see with the developer tools, opera tries to issue a request to whatsapp:// application (using the whatsapp schema) and that is why you are getting the error.

[image]

Comment: If by google you mean chrome then yes, it does not show the error - observe developer tools, chrome does not try to open any links with whatsapp://. To solve it, you will need to add whatsapp to your system and associate it so it would be called by opera when it tries to open the links starting with whatsapp:// ... although you did not ask how to solve the issue, just "How come I am seeing the above msg." :)

Comment: How could I add whatsapp to a pc. WhatsApp Web is not working well

Comment: You simply install it, from this link: https://www.whatsapp.com/download/